# XCode: what is the best way of measuring a code performance?

Tags: c++, c, xcode

Please, tell me, what is the best way of measuring a code performance in Xcode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Instruments`.

Open your project, go in the menu Product > Profile. This will open `Instruments`. The `Time Profiler` instrument is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode includes various performance tools and metrics.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html